# How do you use the function unto in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Today I had a really hard time programming in ruby. I came upon this question, and I was really stumped.

> Print a sequence of number pairs "x,y" such that x ranges from 0 to 3 and y from 5 to 7 *

I already submitted my answer, but I'm not quite sure if I got it right. I'd just like my question answered now for the sake of understanding.

Comment: Are you asking whether you got the right answer, or are you asking Stack Overflow to write the code again?

Comment: Post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0.upto 3 do |x|
  5.upto 7 {|y| puts x, y}
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Something simple like

```
p [*0..3].product([*5..7])
```